# Перевод даты из одного часового пояса в другой

Tags: php, дата, часовые-пояса

Как перевести дату из одного часового пояса в другой?
Дается дата `2015-09-14 10:29:01` , в часовом поясе `Europe/London`

Требуется ее преобразовать в дату но в часовом поясе `Europe/Moscow`
Как это сделать стандартными методами `php`?

+Если есть функции проверки существования часового пояса в базе `php`

Answer (score 5, accepted):

У класса `DateTime` есть функция `SetTimezone` ([доки](http://www.php.net/manual/ru/datetime.settimezone.php))

Т.е. у Вас будет примерно так:

```
$date = new DateTime('2015-09-14 10:29:01', new DateTimeZone('Europe/London'));
echo $date->format('Y-m-d H:i:sP') . '<br>';

$date->setTimezone(new DateTimeZone('Europe/Moscow'));
echo $date->format('Y-m-d H:i:sP');
```

выдаст

```
2015-09-14 10:29:01+01:00
2015-09-14 13:29:01+04:00
```

Comment: А есть функция проверки существования часового пояса на php?

Comment: Что Вы имеете ввиду под "проверка существования"? Часовые пояса существуют. Доказано!..

Comment: Пользователь задает определенный часовой пояс, мне нужно проверить знает ли php такой часовой пояс, если он не знает сказать пользователю об ошибке.

Comment: В PHP внесен список часовых поясов (http://php.net/manual/ru/datetimezone.listidentifiers.php). Вы можете взять этот лист и сравнить с тем, что дал пользователь... Вы это имели ввиду?

Comment: Если DateTime выкидывает ошибку, то думаю ее можно с легкостью отловить и сделать из этого функцию проверки существования определенного часового пояса

Comment: А не легче дать пользователю выбрать из списка существующих поясов? Впрочем, как хотите... Но по-моему, на первый вопрос я, кажется, ответил. А остальное тянет на отдельную дискуссию :)

Comment: Да спасибо, сейчас буду пробовать, напрягает этот +01:00 в конце, от него можно избавится с помощью data, или использовать что-то типо split, регулярные выражения

Comment: Просто смените формат вывода на это `$date->format('Y-m-d H:i:s');`. Галочки и стрелочки ставить не забываем ;)

Comment: Хехе, спасибо не заметил:) все работает отлично, +нашел функцию в часовых поясах на проверку, вывод всех часовых поясов.